Kafka Streams - State Store changelog topic deleteion
I have some corrupted keys in a state store. I dont want to reset the whole application. Can I simply delete and recreate the changelong topic in order to purge the in memory state store. Is this safe?

Adding some context. We have a custom Serde for the state store key, and we seem to have managed to get some corrupted keys in the state store - hence we cant delete the entries by key

Yes, it's just a topic, but deleting the changelog topic would affectively reset the application also

@OneCricketeer by reset, do you mean it would reset that state in that changelog topic (which is what I expect)? I presume the stream source topics would not be affected?

All "internal topics" are deleted by the reset tool. This includes the changelog topics. You'll also need to delete the statestore on disk
https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html
